# Every Category with a Zero Object contains a Connected Groupoid.

Tags: category-theory, groupoids

Let $C$ be a Small Category containing a Zero Object $Z$.

$(\forall{X,Y}\in(Obj(C)))$ define the Zero Morphism $\psi_{X,Y}:X\rightarrow{Y}$ as the composition $\psi_{X,Y}=I_{Y}\circ{T_{X}}$ where $T_{X}:X\rightarrow{Z}$ and $I_{Y}:Z\rightarrow{Y}$ are the Terminal and Initial morphisms respectively.

Define a Subcategory $C\left<Z\right>$ as follows:

- $Obj(C\left<Z\right>) =Obj(C)$
- $\forall{X,Y}\in{Obj(C)}$ $Hom_{C\left<Z\right>}(X,Y)$ $:={I_{Y}\circ{T_{X}}}$ i.e the only morphsisms are the Zero Isomorphisms.

I believe that $C\left<Z\right>$ forms a Connected Grouopoid, and that this construction should work in any Category containing a Zero Object, but I want to make sure I didn't miss anything.

Comment: You say subcategory, but consider identity axiom

Comment: You do not even have identities, because they need not be zero. Also the zero morphisms are far from being invertible if the objects are not themselves zero. The full subcategory spanned by all zero-objects is a contractible groupoid though

Answer (score 1):

There are two main flaws in your construction. Firstly, $C\left<Z\right>$ is not a category whenever it is not a groupoid, as identities of non-zero objects won't be included as morphisms. Secondly, if any arrow is an isomorphism in any subcategory of $C$, it must be also an isomorphism in $C$ itself, as all inverses existing in a subcategory are also morphisms in $C$. Thus again, only in the trivial case of groupoids it makes sense